# Extra hard drive is needed to boot the computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot

While installing my new SSD, I had my extra internal hard drive still all hooked up. After installing Windows 10 on the new SSD, I tried to remove the extra hard drive, just to find out it wont let me boot without it hooked up.

After looking at [this forum post](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2182890/windows-boot-removing-extra-hard-drives.html), it almost seems possible. From the Disk Management, my SSD is listed as "Boot", and the extra is listed as "System". But then Googling how to do a repair install, [this guide](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) says I already need to be logged in and everything.

Am I misunderstanding something? Is this possible? Will I need to do another fresh install on my computer without the extra hard drive attached?

(Please let me know if I left anything out, or you have any questions.)

Answer (score -2):

Managed to figure something out while trolling through even more posts. Downloaded [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and using [this guide](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/209885-bootmgr-move-c-easybcd.html), worked like a charm. I want to note that although the guide sounds like it might only work by moving the boot volume, it also works in reverse (which was my scenario). By selecting the drive which already had the boot volume, and NOT the system volume, it seems the system volume was properly copied over.

Comment: Prime example of making sure you remove all non-critical personal data disks. If you'd have only had the SSD connected then the installer would have installed both boot and system partitions to the SSD with minimal fuss :)

Comment: I'm new to building computers, so this was definitely a learning experience, both in preventative measures, as well as solutions. Kinda confused about the downvote though, but whatever.

Comment: Seems like a post for EasyBCD, question and answer given pretty fast one after another and wording seams familiar!